# Replace the values in the column of a dataframe

Tags: r

```
a<-c('F','M','F','M','M','F')
b<-data.frame(a)
d<- c('1','2')
```

Expected result:

```
  a
1 1
2 2
3 1
4 2
5 2
6 1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Right now you're just giving us vague instructions rather than showing what you've done so far & what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Using `factor` method by specifying the `labels` as 'd'

```
b$a <- factor(b$a, levels = c('F', 'M'), labels = d))
```

---

Or with matching based on a named vector

```
setNames(d, c("F", "M"))[as.character(b$a)]
```